# Command to add a line break (before or after the selection)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a command to add a line before or after the selection?

Here is an example on Atom (duplicating lines downward, then adding a line before selection).

[image: Atom's add-line-break package]

If not, can it be easily added via a package?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty line above with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

You can add an empty line below with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

...at least these are the default shortcuts on windows - other OS might be slightly different, if you can't find it you can open the command pallette and start typing insert line to see the shortcut bindings:

[image: screengrab of command pallette]

Comment: This moves the cursor and doesn't work with multiple selections.
I can't use this to replicate the above GIF, for example.

Comment: It does work for multiple selections - You are correct about it moving the cursor so I do accept the behaviour is different from that gif but I feel my answer does answer the question as asked: "Is there a command to add a line before or after the selection?" Perhaps you should consider another question being a little more specific about the behaviour you need (I don't know if its possible or not without moving the cursor).

Comment: I'd personally recommend NOT editing this original question, however because of this advice: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352334/correct-action-if-you-need-to-change-or-clarify-a-question-as-a-result-of-an-ans

Comment: I just created a more specific question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633403/command-to-add-a-new-line-before-or-after-selections