# Command to add a new line (before or after selections)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a command/package to add a line before or after current selections, that:
1) works with multiple selections,
2) doesn't change selections or move the cursors (except for the offset created by the new lines) ?

I'm aware of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> but these command fail at 2).

Here is an example on Atom (duplicating lines downward, then adding a line before selection).

[image: Atom's add-line-break package]

If not, can it be easily added via a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find anything to do that, so I made a new package:   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dorian-marchal.add-line-break

To install it, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and run `ext install dorian-marchal.add-line-break`.

This will add two new shortcuts:
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>DownArrow</kbd>: Add a line before the selections.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>UpArrow</kbd>: Add a line after the selections.